# What are the key differences between IOTA and Bitcoin? How are they different?

Tags: blockchain, iota

Please explain:
Whats the key working difference between IOTA and Bitcoin?
How does Tangle differ from Blockchain?
 Or link to some resources that define them.

Comment: This question is too broad and shows no research effort. Please read into the subject and ask about specific differences.

Comment: I've asked how Blockchain differs from Tangle in functioning and how IOTA is basically different from Bitcoin. Nothing more than that.

Please excuse me If my english was wrong but that was all I wanted to know.

IOTA is new in the game and their website is a bit confusing for me to understand.